Is it possible to parametrize an exponential expression with these constraints?
I have the following expression
$$y(x) = y_0e^{\tan(\alpha_0)x/y_0}$$
I need to rewrite it in parametric form $[x(t), y(t)]$.
I know I could simply do $x(t) = t$ and theoretically be done, but I need to fulfill some boundary conditions and I don't see how I can do that with this approach.
In particular, I need $$[x'(t),y'(t)]{\LARGE|}_{t=0} = [\cos(\alpha_0), \sin(\alpha_0)]$$ rather than the trivial $[1, \tan(\alpha_0)]$ I would otherwise obtain.
Similarly, I need $$[x'(t),y'(t)]{\LARGE|}_{t=1} = [\cos(\alpha_1), \sin(\alpha_1)]$$ thus making it unfeasible to simply have $x = \cos(\alpha_0)\cdot t$.
NOTE: this condition does not need to be fulfilled at every point of the curve.
I think I am getting caught up in unimportant minutiae and I can't seem to be able to find the path to the solution.
$\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ are given.
EDIT
I'll include here the discussion from the comments.
Someone suggested I take t as the arc length provided by another question here as $t(x)$ and invert that function to obtain $x(t)$.
That's not possible according to WolphramAlpha


This question is similar to: Arc Length of an Exponential Function. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For a parametrization $t\mapsto(x,y)$, the condition "$\forall t,;(x',y')=(\cos\alpha_t,\sin\alpha_t)$ for some $\alpha_t$" is equivalent to $\forall t,;(x')^2+(y')^2=1$, i.e.  $t$ is the arc length.

An implicit assumption is that $y_0$, $\cos\alpha_0$, and $\sin\alpha_0$ are non-zero.
A necessary condition for a solution to exist is then that $\sin\alpha_1$ and $\cos\alpha_1$ are also non-zero and $$\frac{\tan\alpha_1}{\tan\alpha_0}>0,$$ since
$$\begin{cases}y(t)&=y_0e^{\frac{\tan\alpha_0}{y_0}x(t)}\\
x'(1)&=\cos\alpha_1\\
y'(1)&=\sin\alpha_1\end{cases}\implies\sin\alpha_1=y'(1)=\tan\alpha_0e^{\frac{\tan\alpha_0}{y_0}x(1)}\cos\alpha_1.
$$
If these conditions are fulfilled, let
$$x(t)=at^2+bt+c$$ with $a,b$ defined by $$x'(0)=\cos\alpha_0\text{ and }x'(1)=\cos\alpha_1.$$ Then, $y'(0)=\tan\alpha_0x'(0)=\sin\alpha_0$, and there only remains to choose $c$ such that $y'(1)=\sin\alpha_1$, i.e.
$$\ln\frac{\tan\alpha_1}{\tan\alpha_0}=\frac{\tan\alpha_0}{y_0}(a+b+c).$$

thank you. took me a bit to replicate all the steps substituting in the functions for $\alpha_i$ I have, but I get it now. Not sure why I wasn't able to think of using a parabolic $x(t)$
